# C# enum in interface/base class?

Tags: c#, enums, virtual, parent

i have problem with enum

I need make a enum in base class or interface (but empty one)

```
class Base 
{
   public enum Test;
   // ???
}
```

and after make diffrent enums in some parent classes

```
class Parent1
{
   public enum Test {A, B, C};
}

class Parent2
{
   public enum Test {J, H, K};
}
```

and now i have next class with method when i have to use enum

```
class Test<T>
{
   public void Foo(Test enum)
   {
      int value = (int) enum;
      // ...
   }
}
```

It's there any way to do something like that ?

If not i have to use static ints in every class ...

```
class Parent1
{
   public static int A = 0;
   public static int B = 5;
   public static int C = 7;
}

class Parent2
{
   public static int J = 1;
   public static int H = 3;
   public static int K = 6;
}

class Test<T>
{
   public void Foo(int enum)
   {
      int value = enum;
      // ...
   }
}
```

I't looks bad in code ... in some classes i have to use ~20+ variables

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to re-check your assumptions -- why would you need this? Try rephrasing the question to include the thing you're actually trying to get done, instead of focusing on the way you are approaching the problem. :)

Comment: What is it that you want to use it for, really? Having different implementations of the same enum seems to be the opposite of what an enum is intended for...

Comment: @Groo: no, that's adding values to an enum, this is having an abstract enum that has object-specific values, but implements a consistent interface, so its members can be passed around. Marc's answer is the best I've seen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no such thing as an abstract enum (that can have different implementations in subclasses) - but generics may be an option:

```
class Base<T> where T : struct {
    private T value;
    public void Foo(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
class Parent1 : Base<Parent1.Enum1> {
    public enum Enum1 {A, B, C};
}
class Parent2 : Base<Parent2.Enum2> {
    public enum Enum2 { J, H, K };
}
```

The only problem is that this doesn't enforce that only enums are usable - you can do this at runtime, though - for example in a type initializer:

```
static Base() {
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException(
         typeof(T).Name + " is not an enum");
}
```

Comment: well its best possible solution, i can't use only one thing:
abstract public class DB<T> where T : Base<T.Enum>, Interf, new()
i understand why, i have to use static int's not enums then

Comment: "There is no such thing as an abstract enum (that can have different implementations in subclasses) - but generics may be an option:" - WRONG!!! System.Enum is the abstract base for all enumerations

Comment: @SimonBridge please see the context of the question

Answer (score 29):

It's amazing how often I find people arguing about *why* something is required, rather than answering the question asked or keeping schtum - either of which would be more helpful than wasting time questioning *why* a given enquiry has been made in preference to a different enquiry the respondent actually knows the answer to. Answering questions that have not been asked is in no way helpful, OK guys?!

Getting back to the topic at hand, I've hit exactly the above scenario this morning, and can understand why it would be useful to be able to define an Enum in an interface or base class, then re-define that same-named Enum in a class that derives from either the base or interface. One use for such a design is in object-relational mapping and control binding. You might have a set of Enums that describe which Properties of your derived classes are bindable to which types of Control, such as:

```
    public enum WebControlTextBoxProperties { }

    public enum WebControlLabelProperties { }
```

...and so on.

Since you don't know exactly which Properties will exist for a given derived class until the pertinent inheritance takes effect, but since you may also wish to have consistent Methods that consume the above Enums in your base or interface, it's a perfectly-valid design to expect to be able to define that the Enum *will exist* in the base/interface, but define exactly *what members* it has in a specific context in any derived classes.

I really wish this were possible in C# as it is in VB, because it'd be a really useful  feature.

Comment: For me, asking why something is reuired is a way of asking for more information.  Very often the question's answer is "This is not possible." but by finding out why a solution is needed can provide additional options or direction.

Comment: Trisped, sure, but few come out and say "damn, language X can't do that; here is a close alternative." Instead they shift blame to the programmer's intentions, which suggests that the programmer violated a perfect doctrine created by the language designers. That's nonsense. Unrelated, you wrote the best paragraph of 2010 Rachel.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to declare an enum in a base class and then change the values per derived class i.e.

```
class MyClass
{
    public enum TestEnum { }

    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass
{
    public enum TestEnum { value1, value2, value3 }

    public MyDerivedClass()
    {
    }
}
```

MyDervied class would have access to TestEnum.value1, TestEnum.value2, TestEnum.value3, where as MyClass would only have access to the type.

However, personally I don't see the advantage of doing this I would declare ALL the values of the enum in the base class and only use the ones I need per class.

James.

Comment: Problem is - not me create child classes, but some users, and i don't want them to modify main class adding values to this enum

Comment: hmmm and i have a warrning if i use this solution, but its possible to do that:
new public enum TestEnum { value1, value2, value3 }
hmmmm

Comment: Yeah the more I think about what it is your trying to do its not possible. As by declaring new public enum TestEnum will create a separate type of enum to the base class. I think the correct solution would be to have an enum in the base class only.

Comment: seem's like i can't do something like that:
class Test<T> where T : MyClass
{
   public Foo(T.TestEnum te) ...
}
becose it's should be in the interface, and i can't declare types in interface

Comment: but you can just store the enum value as an integer and declare that in the interface instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you define the enum in base class:

```
class Base 
{
   public enum Test {A, B, C, J, H, K};
}
```

And use only the relevant members of enum in derived classes?

Comment: Because of the "open for extension closed for modification" principle. We don't want to change base class when we need a new value in derived class. Instead, we want to extend base class's enum with new values in derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done.

Note that many enums often indicate a problem with design (many switch constructs, for example). Check this link to see an example of how to refactor this: [Replace conditional with polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to enforce anything static in an interface.

Perhaps you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

I am at work so cannot elaborate fully, but this is possible to a point.  The downside to the code below is you cannot chain enums together, such as TextBoxProperties, and MyCustomTextBoxProperties : TextboxProperties

Here is the code.

```
    public enum Test
    {

    }

    public enum ThisTest
    {
        MyVal1,
        MyVal2,
        MyVal3
    }

    public abstract class MyBase
    {
        public Test MyEnum { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDerived : MyBase
    {
        public new ThisTest MyEnum { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**YOU *CAN* ABSTRACT AN ENUM!**

Why do people insist on claiming things are impossible without checking anything?

Sure, the .NET documentation is a little vague on this, but the System.Enum class, IS the abstraction of an enum.  You can use System.Enum as a variable that will ONLY accept enumeration values, and you can access the name or value-type value of the enumeration through this class.

For example:

```
        // abstracted enumeration value
        Enum abstractEnum = null;

        // set to the Console-Color enumeration value "Blue";
        abstractEnum = System.ConsoleColor.Blue;

        // the defined value of "ConsoleColor.Blue" is "9":
        // you can get the value via the ToObject method:
        Console.WriteLine((int)Enum.ToObject(abstractEnum.GetType(), abstractEnum));

        // or via the GetHashCode() method:
        Console.WriteLine(abstractEnum.GetHashCode());

        // the name can also be acessed:
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(abstractEnum.GetType(), abstractEnum));
```

The output from the above code:

9

9

Blue

Comment: This is a really bad idea. `Enum` is not an `enum`. Any time you use `Enum` as a field/variable type (for example `Enum abstractEnum`) you are adding boxing, completely unnecessarily. It is misleading to claim that `Enum` is the abstraction of an `enum`, in the same way that it is misleading to claim that `object` is the abstraction of a `struct`. The runtime is capable of *treating* it like that, but at some non-trivial cost.

Comment: Just 'cos something is a little inefficient doesn't mean it's wrong, besides, I didn't say it was a good idea, I just said it works.

Comment: Define 'non trivial' anyway... are you calling a boxing operation 'non trivial' in the context of an everyday .NET application? If you are worried about the performance impact of boxing operations on an enumeration value then you should be using a non-managed programming language like C++, I'm afraid .NET just isn't fast enough that you would notice the difference, it is after all a managed runtime, NOT a realtime system.

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted answer of @Marc Gravell.
As i am a stackoverflow-newbie i am not allowed to comment. But i would like to add, that it is useful to also check the underlying Type of the enum - especially if you use the Flag Attribute and preform bit-wise flag-Testing operations...

```
if ( !typeof(T).IsEnum || typeof(int) != Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) )
{
     throw new InvalidOperationException( typeof(T).Name + " is not an enum");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works for me:

in the parent class, declare the field as int, not as enum:

```
protected int state;
```

so the parent class can still use this value as an int, in order to provide serialization and deserializion of this value to disk.

Then, who overrides the class can do this:

```
enum states{
  state1, state2
}

this.state = state1.toInt();
```

and can access the actual value like this:

```
...
if (this.state == states.state1.toInt()){
      ...
}
else{
     ...
}
```

where toInt() is defined in a static class as follows:

```
public static class Utils
{

    public static int toInt(this state s)
    {
        return (int)s;
    }
 }
```