# Handle Multiple List-Types

Tags: c#, enums

Below is my code. How do I capture EnumList1 and EnumList2 by using only one property?

```
public class TestClass
    {
        private string FirstName;
        private string LastName;
        // Need to capture EnumList1 and EnumList2 in one property
    }

    public enum EnumList1
    {
        Item1 = 1,
        Item2 = 2
    }

    public enum EnumList2
    {
        Item3 = 1,
        Item4 = 2
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you combine the enum's ?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle", and why do you only want one property?

Comment: What do you mean by "list types". I don't see any `List`, only enums.

Comment: Only in conditional way you can do probably ... I mean if you want to get the value from property ... then probably you can do like `if(some condition) then EnumList1.Item1 else EnumList2.Item1`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I need to display these enum values (from either EnumList1 or EnumList2) in a listbox based on a condition. When saving to the db, i create an object of TestClass and save it.

Comment: @stech: That's still not really a good explanation of what you're trying to do... Why do you need a single property? Why not two properties, only one of which gets set?

Comment: IF I have 10 more lists tomorrow, adding 10 more properties may not make sense, there has to be a way to do this, i dnt know how?

Answer (score 2):

my initial thought had been some way to 'abstract' the enum, but no such methodology exists. however, marc gravell has addressed your scenario to some degree here:

[C# enum in interface/base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031620/c-sharp-enum-in-interface-base-class)

i'm sure it'll help you going fwd to the next bit of the puzzle.